# How can I determine the transaction id (XID) of my Derby connection to correspond with the SYSCS_DIAG.LOCK_TABLE

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am working on debugging some deadlock issues with a Derby database, and I was wondering if it was possible to get the XID for my JDBC Connection to Derby that corresponds to the XID column in the SYSCS_DIAG.LOCK_TABLE.

If I do a toString on my connection I get something like this:

> org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40@233639405 (XID = 182818), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = mydb), (DRDAID = null)

And while that XID is similar (in approximate numeric range) with the numbers in the XID columns of a SELECT * FROM SYSCS_DIAG.LOCK_TABLE, it is not equal to a number in that column, ever. So, what gives? How do I get the XID that matches a number in that table?